# Validation not working properly when editing p:autoComplete

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces `autocomplete` component with `multiple="true"`. This component is working fine at the time of adding. But when I am trying to do any update, it is always giving validation error saying the value is required even though the value is properly displaying.This is my code

```
<p:autoComplete id="entitySpecId" multiple="true" inputStyle="width: 100%" queryDelay="500"
                            size="50" value="#{equipTemplateBean.selectedEntities}"
                            completeMethod="#{equipTemplateBean.completeAssnEntity}" var="spec"
                            itemLabel="#{spec.specName}" itemValue="#{spec}" converter="specificationConverter"
                             required="true">
                            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{equipTemplateBean.entityMultiSelect}" update="messagePanel" />
                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{spec.specName}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:autoComplete>
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Code for   **SpecificationConverter.java**

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
    if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
      EquipmentTemplateBean templateBean = null;
      try {
        if (fc != null) {
          ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
          templateBean = (EquipmentTemplateBean) elContext.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "equipTemplateBean");
        }
        if (null != templateBean && null != templateBean.getAllSpecsList()) {
          for (Specification spec : templateBean.getAllSpecsList()) {
            if (null != spec && Integer.parseInt(value) == spec.getSpecificationId().intValue()) {
              return spec;
            }
          }
          return null;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid entity."));
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: show us SpecificationConverter.java

Comment: I have updated the question with specificationconverter

Comment: Can you see in debug mode which return statement in this method is hit when form is submitted?

Comment: Known issue in PrimeFaces 0.9.2

Comment: @Kukeltje  PrimeFaces 0.9.2 ? Which version is this? and when PF team released it.

Comment: @dileepH Which version of Primefaces you are using?

Comment: @Subodh: you're taking sarcasm too literally. OP just didn't mention this crucial information anywhere. Dileep, carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info to learn how to get better answers faster.

Comment: @BalusC No way to do "sarcasm"  with anyone. If Kukeltje dont know the version he have to ask and not to predict .

Comment: @Kukeltje I am using prime faces version 5.3

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar it is not even coming to converter

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: I don't have to do anything, it is all voluntarily. OP should do most of the work, including creating a 'good' question (good title to, see the 'edits'). And the version was so unrealistic that is was not a prediction, not by a long shot.

Comment: So if it is not coming to the converter, it does not play a role? Try with plain Strings then, without converter. Does that work?

Comment: @Kukeltje Everyone here is volunteer and i saw 60% in SO don't have good title/description but they got good answer plenty of +1. I am not saying we should now follow the guidelines of SO but for a new user its quite typical FYI you can check our own question/answer which we asked couple of year back.

Comment: 46 reputation is not a new user

Comment: @dileepH In addition to `@Kukeltje suggestion of removing converter and using strings, please remove required="true" and see what value is being set